# Converting Expression<Func<DTO,bool>> to Expression<Func<Domain, bool>>

Tags: c#, .net, linq, wcf

I'm using [Expression Tree Serializer](https://expressiontree.codeplex.com/) for sending Expression< FuncDTO,bool>> to WCF services and

my repository is working with Domain type. I want to apply this expression for my repository

```
Expression<Func<UserDto,bool>> expression = new ExpressionSerializer().Deserialize<Func<UserDto, bool>>(xmlElement);
var addressBookEntries = addressBooksRepository.Where(expression); //accepts Expression<Func<UserDomain,bool>>
```

How can I fix this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used dynamic linq and it solved my problem, only little issue property names must be equals. I converted dynamic linq to string and sent it thorough wcf service and using it as string

```
using System.Linq;
using System.Linq.Dynamic;

    public ICollection<UserDto> GetUsersByFilter(string filter)
    {
        var addressBooksRepository = new AddressBooksRepository();
        var addressBookEntries = addressBooksRepository.GetAll().Where(filter);
                //return data
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try create new expression with your type arguments based on existed one.

```
public class UserDto : UserDomain
{ }

public class UserDomain
{ }

void YourMethod()
{
     Expression<Func<UserDto, bool>> expression = new ExpressionSerializer().Deserialize<Func<UserDto, bool>>(xmlElement);
     Func<UserDto, bool> func = expression.Compile();
     Expression<Func<UserDomain, bool>> newExpression = x => func(x as UserDto);
     var addressBookEntries = addressBooksRepository.Where(newExpression);
}
```